# Disable tab cloning after 3rd clone

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help to disable the 'Add Friend' tab after the 3rd tabs entry. I've no idea how to solve this, I've been googling around and still can't find the best solutions. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Bootply Version - http://www.bootply.com/LCQIOKXudR

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  })
  .on("click", "span", function() {
    var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
    $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
  });


$('.add-contact').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; //think about it ;)

  var num = $('.clonedInput').length, // Checks to see how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    newNum = new Number(num + 1), // The numeric ID of the new input field being added, increasing by 1 each time
    newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value

  $(this).closest('li').before('<li class="active"><a href="#contact_' + id + '">Friend ' + id + '</a><span class="badge">x</span></li>');
  $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="contact_' + id + '"><h2 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">Friend ' + id + '</h2><div class="form-group"><label class="label_fn control-label" for="first_name">First name:</label><input id="friend_first_name' + id + '" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn form-control" required=""></div></div>');
});
```

```css
.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
  position: relative;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav-tabs > li > span {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 8px;
  color: red;
}
.nav-tabs > li:hover > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#contact_01" data-toggle="tab">Friend</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" id="addBtn" class="add-contact" data-toggle="tab">+ Add Friend</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="contact_01">


      <div id="entry1" class="clonedInput">
        <h2 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">Friend 1</h2>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="label_fn control-label" for="first_name">First name:</label>
          <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn form-control" required="">
        </div>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change Made**

```
if($('.nav.nav-tabs li').length < 4  ){
```

> Added an extra condition to check number of tabs

**Working Demo**

```js
$(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).tab('show');
    })
    .on("click", "span", function () {
        var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
        $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
    });
        
        
    $('.add-contact').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       if($('.nav.nav-tabs li').length < 4  ){
       
        var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; //think about it ;)

        var num     = $('.clonedInput').length, // Checks to see how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
            newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      // The numeric ID of the new input field being added, increasing by 1 each time
            newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
        
        $(this).closest('li').before('<li class="active"><a href="#contact_'+id+'">Friend '+id+'</a><span class="badge">x</span></li>');         
        $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="contact_'+id+'"><h2 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">Friend '+id+'</h2><div class="form-group"><label class="label_fn control-label" for="first_name">First name:</label><input id="friend_first_name'+id+'" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn form-control" required=""></div></div>');
         }
      else{
        alert("Not aloowed")
      }
    });
```

```css
.btn-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
    position:relative;    
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
    display:inline-block;
}

.nav-tabs > li > span {
    display:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 8px;
    color: red;
}

.nav-tabs > li:hover > span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">                

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#contact_01" data-toggle="tab">Friend</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="addBtn" class="add-contact" data-toggle="tab">+ Add Friend</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="contact_01">
 

        <div id="entry1" class="clonedInput">
          <h2 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">Friend 1</h2>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="label_fn control-label" for="first_name">First name:</label>
          <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn form-control" required="">
        </div>


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You're already checking the number of existing tabs, so you can simply check it's less than three before appending a new tab:

```
$('.add-contact').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length;

  if (id <= 3) {
    // append new tab here...
  }
});
```

```js
$(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  })
  .on("click", "span", function() {
    var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
    $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
  });


$('.add-contact').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length;

  if (id <= 3) {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length,
      newNum = new Number(num + 1),
      newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow');

    $(this).closest('li').before('<li class="active"><a href="#contact_' + id + '">Friend ' + id + '</a><span class="badge">x</span></li>');
    $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="contact_' + id + '"><h2 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">Friend ' + id + '</h2><div class="form-group"><label class="label_fn control-label" for="first_name">First name:</label><input id="friend_first_name' + id + '" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn form-control" required=""></div></div>');
  }
});
```

```css
.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.nav-tabs > li {
  position: relative;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav-tabs > li > span {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 8px;
  color: red;
}
.nav-tabs > li:hover > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#contact_01" data-toggle="tab">Friend</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" id="addBtn" class="add-contact" data-toggle="tab">+ Add Friend</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="contact_01">
      <div id="entry1" class="clonedInput">
        <h2 id="reference" name="reference" class="heading-reference">Friend 1</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="label_fn control-label" for="first_name">First name:</label>
          <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input_fn form-control" required="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.